# Validate a phone number with React Native Phone Number Input?

Tags: react-native

How can i format then check if the phone number is valide to make the update with with [React Native Phone Number Input](https://github.com/garganurag893/react-native-phone-number-input#methods) ? i used the `isValidNumber`funtion to check if the number is valid but i want to format it before with `onChangeFormattedText` method :

```
    export default class PhoneUserInput extends PureComponent {
    ...
    render() {
    return (
    <PhoneInput
              onChange={(value) => {
   isValidNumber(value) ? updateNumber('phoneNumber', value) : value
    }
              defaultValue={defaultValue}
              placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
              defaultCode="US"
              keyboardType="phone-pad"
              withDarkTheme
              withShadow
              autoFocus
              textContainerStyle={{
                backgroundColor: 'black',
              }}
              textInputStyle={{
                color: '#fff',
                fontFamily: 'calibri',
                fontSize: Fonts.sizes.header,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                borderBottomColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)',
              }}
              codeTextStyle={{
                color: '#fff',
              }}
              flagButtonStyle={{
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                color: '#fff',
              }}
            />
    );
      }
    }
```

Comment: why don't u put the check in onchangeformatted?

Comment: Does the function `onChangeFormattedText`contains the formated value how can i access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access your onChangeFormattedText like this

```
onChangeFormattedText={(text) => {
        isValidNumber(text) ? updateNumber('phoneNumber', text) : text
        setFormattedText(text);
        console.log(text
        
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for saving me for the second time lol